# Flutter Search Delegate with Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I m implementing a search feature using Flutter Search Delegate and the data is stored in Firestore. I can't figure out why this error is coming up.

```
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('todos').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');

      final results =
          snapshot.data.documents.where((a) => a['title'].contains(query));

      return ListView(
        children: results.map<Widget>((a) => Text(a['title'])).toList(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Error:

`type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(DocumentSnapshot) => bool' of 'test'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the line

```
final results = snapshot.data.documents.where((a) => a['title'].contains(query));
```

to

```
final results = snapshot.data.documents.where((DocumentSnapshot a) => a.data['title'].contains(query));
```

And the line

```
children: results.map<Widget>((a) => Text(a['title'])).toList()
```

to

```
children: results.map<Widget>((a) => Text(a.data['title'])).toList()
```

Comment: still getting error `type '(DocumentSnapshot) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(DocumentSnapshot) => bool' of 'test'`

Comment: try `a.data['title'].toString().contains(query)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got the solution:                                                   
`final results = snapshot.data.documents.where((DocumentSnapshot a) => a.data['title'].toString().contains(query));`

`children: results.map<Widget>((a) => Text(a.data['title'].toString())).toList()`

Answer (score -1):

Replace the Line

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  ....
```

With

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
.....
```

Final code be :

```
 Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');

        final results =
            snapshot.data.docs.where((a) => a['title'].contains(query));

        return ListView(
          children: results.map<Widget>((a) => Text(a['title'])).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```